# How do I check if an int is between 0 and 3?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a script I want to print "x is equal to..." if x is between 0 and 3, and print "x is not equal to 0-3" if it is greater than 4 or lesser than 0. The way I have it right now though, it will print "x is equal to..." as long as x is less than 4, and will only print "x is not equal to 0-3" if it is greater than 4.

I am just beginning to learn python so I haven't really tried anything yet and wouldn't know where to begin.

This is the relevant code to the issue.

```
x = 0
if x < 4:
    print("x is equal to", x)
elif x < 4:    
    print("x is not equal to 0-3")
```

As you can see, as long as x is lower than 4 it will print "x is equal to...", when I want it to only print that if it is lower than 4 but higher than -1, and I also want it to print "x is not equal to 0-3" if it is less than 0.

Comment: Hello and welcome ! You jsut need to add an "and" condition to your first if: `if x >= 0 and x < 4:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job quite nicely;

```
x = 0
if 0 <= x <= 3:
    print("x is equal to", x)
else:   
    print("x is not between 0 and 3")
```

---

You can also use the `and` operator, there is little to no difference between those examples but knowing that it exists is still worth.

```
if 0 <= x and x <= 3:
     print("x is equal to", x)
else:
     print("x is not between 0 and 3")
```

You can add as much `and` condition you want, and side note: the `or` operator also exists and can be useful.

Comment: It would be worth noting that it works because unlike most other languages, Python allows chaining comparison operator with cheir conventional interpretation.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm not sure why I had an elif statement there rather than an else statement. That being said, I tried your suggestion and with this as my code:


    x = 2

    if 0 <= x >= 3:

        print("x is equal to", x)

    else:

        print("x is not equal to 0-3")

it prints "x is not equal to 0-3"

Comment: @ruhola done, sorry it was telling me I had to wait 2 minutes for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. Here is another version, using the `range` function.

```
x=5
if x in range(0, 3):
        print("x is equal to "+  str(x) )  
else:
    print "x is not between 0 and 3"
```